# Transforming a rectangle into a ring

Tags: math, graphics, transform

I have a rectangle that I need to 'bend' into a ring, i.e. the top edge of the rectangle must map to the outer circle of the ring, the bottom to the inner circle, and the sides of the rectangle should join.

Here's an extremely crude sketch of the rectangle and ring:
[image]

If it is helpful or necessary, I can deal with the rectangle as a collection of horizontal lines, and the ring as a collection of circles.

The rectangle has a horizontal gradient from a to b that should map so that the gradient progresses on a circular direction.

I can see that this is a non-linear transform, but am lost as to where to look to learn the techniques to solve this problem. Could anyone with suitable experience in CG point me to anything like the right text, the right name of algorithm or the right graphics library to make my ring?

Comment: You say that it is a nonlinear transformation. What you need to recognize is that you can view a number in any way you wish. It may be the coordinates of a point inside a rectangle. Or as easily it can be a viewed in terms of the coordinates of a point in polar form. Numbers are just that - numbers. Only your mind adds meaning to a set of numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try just using [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates). If you map x as r and y as θ (normalising as θ runs from 0 to 2π), then adding some offset to r will vary the radius of the ring and adding an offset to θ will rotate it around the circle.

```
r = fx + a
g = (max_y - min_y)/(2*pi)
theta = gy + b
```

where a and b are these offsets, f scales the width of the ring and g normalizes the length of the rectangle to 2π. The transform back from these polar coordinates to cartesian (i.e. the screen) is just:

```
x' = r cos(theta)
y' = r sin(theta)
```

You then have 3 coordinate systems: (x,y) for the original rectangle, (r,θ) for the polar coordinates of the ring and (x',y') for the screen coordinates.